# SAPUI5 Custom Launchpad Tile: Chip definition with Component

Tags: sapui5

I'll add a custom tile for my Fiori Launchpad. More precisely, I like to use a component instead of a view in my Chip Definition File. The reason why is getting the option for eg. load my own I18n or CSS files.

The Chip definition is descriped [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4645cacaceb4435dbd1de9354512069e/2.10/en-US/91ebf3ff6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html). On your Server you can find a description by using this URL: http://:/sap/public/bc/ui2/services/sap/ui2/srvc/chipdefinition.xsd

The chipdefinition.xsd from your own server provides the option loading a custom tile by Component and not by View. The specific tag can be found under: chip => implementation => sapui5 => **viewName or componentName**.

I would like to use "componentName" instead of "viewName" but I can't find a dokumentation for this specific usage. Does anybody know how to add your own Path/Namespace to access the component.js?

The usage by using "viewName" is descriped as follows: "*The viewName comprises package path, the name of the view and the file extension, for example tests.sample.Myview.view.xml.*" But this syntax doesn't work for "componentName"

Thanks for your Help!!

Jimboh

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement the tile as SAPUI5 Components.

Instead of a SAPUI5 view (sap.ui.core.mvc.View), try using a component by specifying the component's name instead (sap.ui.core.UIComponent). Note that this refers to the folder where SAPUI5 expects a Component.js file to be found.

/hana/sap/hba/apps/kpi/WebContent/KPITile/resources/Kpi.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) 2013 SAP AG, All Rights Reserved -->
<chip xmlns="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui2/services/Chip/1">
  <implementation>
    <sapui5>
      <basePath>../../../../../../..</basePath>
      <componentName>sap.hba.apps.kpi.WebContent.KPITile.resources</componentName>
    </sapui5>
  </implementation>
</chip>
```